# Use calc() function in makeStyles

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss, inline-styles

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  dialog: {
    '& .MuiTextField-root': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
    }
  },
  address: {
    width:"calc(24vw + 8px)"
  },
}));
```

```
<div>
 <TextField id="contact-tel" style={{width:'10vw'}} label="联系电话" inputRef={tellRef} margin='none' />
 <TextField id="contact-company" style={{width:'14vw'}} label="公司名称" inputRef={companyRef} margin='none' />
</div>
<div>
  <TextField id="contact-address" className={classes.address} label="收件地址" inputRef={addressRef} margin='none' />
</div>
```

Code as above, but I didn't the right thing, don't know where is the problem? not support vw + px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your styles has lower priority than the one from MUI, try adding a couple of [ampersands](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.8.1#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule) to increase the CSS specificity.

```
address: {
  width: "calc(24vw + 8px)",
  "&&": {
    width: "calc(24vw + 8px)" // same as the above but with higher priority
  }
}
```

### References

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
- https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.8.1#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule

Comment: Thanks  it works , as the priority  ,it is a  new thing for me , is there some doc for that ?

Comment: @will it's basic knowledge in CSS. you may have a styles somewhere that set the width which has a classname, for example `.MuiTextField-root`, if you add `&&` in your styles, yours has 2 duplicated classNames, something like `.makeStyles-1.makeStyles-1`, because 2 is larger than 1, your styles overrides the other one.