# Reactjs / Material-UI: className does not work on the ToggleButton component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, classname

Using React / Material UI, I am trying to apply styles to a group of `ToggleButton`s .

Currently I can only define the `style` prop for each `ToggleButton` to make it work.

I am trying to do `className={...}` instead, to make the code better.

However, I found that this does not work for `ToggleButton` components:

```
import ToggleButton from '@mui/material/ToggleButton';
import ToggleButtonGroup from '@mui/material/ToggleButtonGroup';

import useStyles from './styles'; 


const DashboardSettings = () = {

  const classes = useStyles(); 



  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Paper className={classes.paper} elevation={10}>  // here works
        <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
          Settings
        </Typography>
        <br />
        <br />
        <Grid spacing={3} container>
          <Grid xs={12} item>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <p>Holiday(s): </p>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={1}></Grid>
              <Grid item xs={10}>
                <ToggleButtonGroup
                  // value={formats}
                  onChange={() => {}}
                  // fullWidth
                  aria-label="text formatting"
                  mt={10}
                >
                  <ToggleButton value="mon" className={classes.toggleButton}> // here it has no effect! 
                    <p>Monday</p>
                  </ToggleButton>        

                  <ToggleButton value="mon" style={{marginRight: "5px", marginLeft: "5px", backgroundColor: "#FCDC00"}}>  
                    <p>Monday</p>
                  </ToggleButton>               

                  <ToggleButton value="tue" style={{marginRight: "5px", marginLeft: "5px", backgroundColor: "#FCDC00"}}>
                    <p>Tuesday</p>
                  </ToggleButton>

                  <ToggleButton value="wed" style={{marginRight: "5px", marginLeft: "5px", backgroundColor: "#FCDC00"}}>
                    <p>Wednesday</p>
                  </ToggleButton>

                  <ToggleButton value="thu" style={{marginRight: "5px", marginLeft: "5px", backgroundColor: "#FCDC00"}}>
                    <p>Thursday</p>
                  </ToggleButton>

                  <ToggleButton value="fri" style={{marginRight: "5px", marginLeft: "5px", backgroundColor: "#FCDC00"}}>
                    <p>Friday</p>
                  </ToggleButton>

                  <ToggleButton value="sat" style={{marginRight: "5px", marginLeft: "5px", backgroundColor: "#FCDC00"}}>
                    <p>Saturday</p>
                  </ToggleButton>                                        

                  <ToggleButton value="sun" style={{marginRight: "5px", marginLeft: "5px", backgroundColor: "#FCDC00"}}>
                    <p>Sunday</p>
                  </ToggleButton>

                </ToggleButtonGroup>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={1}></Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>


  )


}
```

./styles.js:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'; 

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(3),
    padding: theme.spacing(20),

    [theme.breakpoints.up(600 + theme.spacing(3) * 2)]: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(6),
      marginBottom: theme.spacing(6),
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
    },
  },

  toggleButton: {
    marginRight: "5px", 
    marginLeft: "5px", 
    color: "#000000",
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
  },

})); 

export default useStyles;
```

Why does it not work?
here is a view of it:
[image]

How can I apply styles to these buttons in a neater way then?

Comment: It's the css specificity issue. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69657385/9449426) answer.

Answer (score 0):

these components are not dom(document object model) elements. instead, they are a wrapper around the dom-elements and they pass some of the values to element attributes through props. so if props aren't.

**Also** it might be the case that when you provide styles through className in that scenarios style directly provided to element have more specificity than you class-Styles. it's better to use decorators like **!important.**
ex.

```
height: '120px !important',
```

```js
export const ToggleButton = (props) => {
  //you can only pass those props which is being used here.
  //  here i am using className as props and further i have passed to original elements.
  // in your case there  is no className attribute.
  const  {onClick, style, className, children, text, type}  = props;

  return (
      <button onClick={onClick} style={style} className={className} type={type}>
      {children || text}
     </button>
  )
}
```

available then you can't pass that to the component as there is no implementation for the same.

Comment: I solved it with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69657329/use-calc-function-in-makestyles/69657385#69657385

Comment: that's also good.