# Remove highlight on mouse leave in MUI Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using `Autocomplete` and hovering over the list of options, and moving the mouse out of it leaves the latest option, that the mouse was hovering over, still highlighted.

What's the best way to remove highlight when the mouse pointer is outside of the list altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handlers to know when the mouse is inside the `Listbox` and override the background if the mouse is outside and the option is focused. Note that the [double ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69657385/9449426) is necessary to increase the CSS specificity and put your styles above the one from MUI:

```
const [mouseInListBox, setMouseInListBox] = React.useState(false);

return (
  <Autocomplete
    {...props}
    ListboxProps={{
      onMouseEnter: () => setMouseInListBox(true),
      onMouseLeave: () => setMouseInListBox(false),
      sx: {
        '&& li.Mui-focused': {
          bgcolor: !mouseInListBox ? 'white' : undefined,
        },
      },
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
  />
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Would you also happen to know how is it possible to de-focus the option after the mouse has left the list box completely? Because this solution removes the highlight, but if `Autocomplete` is in `freeSolo` mode, and you click enter, it will select the previously highlighted option anyway.

Comment: @user1563544 you can't manipulate the current highlighted index as it's a private variable in [`useAutocomplete`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-core/src/AutocompleteUnstyled/useAutocomplete.js#L773), see my updated codesandbox for a potential workaround.